# Security issue using Nant

Tags: encryption, nant, nantcontrib, nant-task

I need to store authentication information and I rather not have the password in plain text:

```
<property name="user"      value="theUser"/>  
<property name="password"  value="secret"/>
```

Has anyone figured out a way to encrypt property values in Nant?
I've looked in Nant and Nantcontrib docs but no mention of encryption. I am considering going the route of creating my own Nant Task.

Any suggestions?

Comment: hi Diego. Did you find a workaround for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't find a workaround.  I am starting to think the only route is to create your own task, however, I have not gotten a chance to get to it.  Sorry!